# Подскажите как привести подобный обфусцированный код к читаемому состоянию

Tags: lua

Подскажите как привести подобный обфусцированный код к читаемому состоянию (Или отпишите что это за обфускатор, если знаете).

```
q([[ssifn(uEnwqxqifij#qpcal&m.q0j.=uzrkok1k{}h3yuyori0gvvqaz1yvvoth0ngp4Jrppu#ntdeq!l4v,v-o=wsxvk/Ttd{VYM/clfu5AjhVf~v1LzWatok1iqbnzs&spkdn!d3c-w/x1w?Zfz\0[hsK1TskirTsg}gy/joum0Fii0xyxjrg.btj'rrkds(mDynyk/Iykdxi!mwkfm(k0T,m=qlu4[vhtw1shv6Wyi|i[yrmom4uh{6VioiUs[guzmt$osfcq G-v?S{qErnttsfEvqmivg4nhu.Skfmn}e#lojbn!S?KrfhugCnmivxJotWbs-'jl_mrvoohevonif/4/‚ipcu-0xxvh.srcer'b=jgqtf npdfo!gB|^hgpuhe>-ot{u=27t{z6zwmfftljj0~atih}2ujt/u|uCzskbqhs?,t(zexy@,x+.\vs{i]E-kyur?30ewq/sk|wvktsu4teen1hiqi5zvw.rkuAyujfrjuD,t-{m||C({(1Ѓmuhap'i|shzktq!y/o.opcep"t?h)s2+\^+}#…-5%.a/3i}uhvlor+i-sogdq"jEr-+^,-w.f.vhtzus*-20/.i-m)?D3gsd(6+tv,/,51f$mqk0yev}up e,u1-'+.,,+,gvl%|+Unjqk3-oslvjimi}kNv~otollc-3j}tf|orn+0|oqet/Tomppi034lxrdukqt,1lpjar jArgbca4,Ѓilct-1r-..--k)j0)pusrcЃ'7k.,mzohuitq)f-qg'zl,xifv#l?SlxQr{0p+.=LeuQpy(1,j<Zhv\unxng9+l<Xof+/dDlemvi'krtg#gAvwwi#fth!mvk0enl,lqup2Vjpsvl)(Ullur..(pukwmaomziIvvqykrma,)epf.oqkir!fDg+3356=,0,x-/VrVtdzhsChav(-VsVtberKpd|_Hwtmlj.4fzpivmsp.u3g2u.v,n;EwZulhi)h0epiq4wqqchy@{|txdpingE,Х›ЦґСЉРёС†+4lobnipg=.zfpiw+0|rxbqcnk>)Т•Ц…РГТѕРГ(0lpatingD.lxmko'„4v}doctm>+УЎТБЦЃУµСѕТі.1fqdpfrj?-ostbue/}1ЃywbrcpkD'У”ТГЦЅФ‚Уі,0jrevfqg>,aqЃtw.~3‚xxfrgomA/СћЦБРЅЦґУЅ.,kpbnerf>otb{h-ѓ1subodpm@-У”С¶ЧєХєУБ-4gvgqareD-lerm)0m|skwpoo"v2Iiz]pkchy-w1htw!{3l!ln%l)n4woiil{0dr%nn!s@ImtZwike+u1=El6kuavioe#xijq%ti{yuu(l3u{`vanh&eoi#jni!lrf&qreen'l&v,kwrvuhlcn6uuhs|.,kxri|nqqg/il&y0l,zlfo"iBYesowk+1ipe"eAt.+EJshok'-i<Wh{[p{k,6053881)g=Fjn|mu+1k<VkwKtajmbipl+ts|l0eBZhs~FrvveBwwtwr)gbluge;Yi|Wo{me/)Hoshrm!zqjhch/.iBTcrjUut}p0/mqjhm"u>o0,nuhio#sDs/'FHptdvCt~/0f)o>TkyWk‚m.3763741sAXmuTpv,0,62/q?Dmp{ixKsvl|uoxdl)0s;[i{\qslujt+Ц™️ФБХЅФБХ‡,$РјХЖХ‰УѕФ€Х‹ШБ'ТёХГСІСЕЩ‚ХЅЩЉ Ф‡У·ЦЕСЅ"ХВТёЩѓТЃРЖЦѕР±Фѕ.,q<Vfy]et|h-s/IkuZpiijy0x.1gsz"u/f%mv$i)o2vpqfiu0eq#p<GhdDiunek0f5wwaqeqh)jqf!s6VvSjnlfvBlwqivqrv0m3e4o,npx$r.l&ps#j(p.vpkdj{)lv(ni$pCEj.vzbpeqf$vkkv!ruibn&g@f6kt_rfnl'j(/gpw{vfmkh1ipj-)Z(m0i-H))knbiwsnoic}q
```

Comment: Думаю что стоит обратиться к владельцу даного кода, он сможет точно сказать что за обфускатор использован.

Comment: Этот "код" надо как минимум открыть в Hex редакторе и вставить сюда бинарное представление, ведь очевидно, что это не текстовые данные, а некий бинарь.

Answer (score 2):

Может это `luac` попробуйте программу `unluac`. https://wfcrydoc.fandom.com/ru/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_.LUA_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2